# MySQL : first day of the week and last day of the week not working as desired

Tags: mysql, date

I have a `table` named `stockins` with a `column` `stock`.
In that I want to find `max(stock)` between first date of the week and last date of the week.

To do that I am using the following query

```
select max(stock) 
from stockins 
where date >= '(DATE(NOW()) - INTERVAL (WEEKDAY(DATE(NOW()))) DAY)' 
and date <= '(DATE(NOW() + INTERVAL (6 - WEEKDAY(NOW())) DAY))'
```

But the output is coming wrong.

If I run the below query

```
select max(stock) 
from stockins 
where date >= '(DATE(NOW()) - INTERVAL (WEEKDAY(DATE(NOW()))) DAY)' 
and date <= '2018-01-28'
```

Then I am getting the desired output.

Where I could be going wrong?

Comment: @RaymondNijland `datatype` of the `column` date is `date`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just remove Single quotes.

```
select max(stock) from stockins where date >= (DATE(NOW()) - INTERVAL (WEEKDAY(DATE(NOW()))) DAY) and date <= (DATE(NOW() + INTERVAL (6 - WEEKDAY(NOW())) DAY))
```